# Removing items that do not exist in JSON from an array

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps

I get the JSON Data:

```
[
  {"id":'1029',
    "position":
        {
        "lat":'40.690902',
        "long":'-73.993449'
        }
  }
]
```

then process the data and add each marker to the `myMarkers` and create a marker, or if it already exists, update the position on the map:

```
// Remember markers
var myMarkers = {};

***// Code removed here which gets JSON via ajax //***

// Move data to res variable, just for fun..
var res = data;

// Process the data..
for(var i=0, len=res.length; i<len; i++) {

    // Does this marker exist?
    if(myMarkers.hasOwnProperty(res[i].id)) {

        // Update position
        myMarkers[res[i].id].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(res[i].position.lat,res[i].position.long));

    } else {
    // It does NOT exist, create it ..

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(res[i].position.lat,res[i].position.long),
            map:map,
        });    

        myMarkers[res[i].id] = marker;

    }   

}
```

So far, so good. Now, I've run into the problem that the JSON data may be missing some items that were created earlier and are already on the map. In which case I want them removed completely from the `myMarkers` and wiped from the map. I can't get my head around how to accomplish this. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I tried the following to "reverse" the process but it doesn't seem to work even though it would make sense (to me at least):

```
for(var i=0, len=myMarkers.length; i<len; i++) {
                console.log("Checking reverse..");

                    //Do we have this marker already?
                    if(data.hasOwnProperty(res[i].id)) {

                        console.log(res[i].id+" exists ..");
                        // Remove it here..

                    } else {

                        console.log(res[i].id+" does NOT exist ..");
                        // Do nothing

                    }


                }
```

I am sure I am only a tiny bit wrong, but I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample code snippet that shows how you can delete markers from `myMarkers`object that are not present in JSON array `dataJSON`

```js
let dataJSON = [
  {
   "id":'1',
    "position":
        {
        "lat":'40.690902',
        "long":'-73.993449'
        }
  },
  {
   "id":'3',
    "position":
        {
        "lat":'40.690902',
        "long":'-74.993449'
        }
  },
  {
   "id":'5',
    "position":
        {
        "lat":'41.690902',
        "long":'-73.993449'
        }
  }
];

let myMarkers = {
 '1': new Object(),
  '2': new Object(),
  '3': new Object(),
  '4': new Object(),
  '5': new Object()
};

let idsFromJSON = dataJSON.map(jsonElem => jsonElem.id);
console.log("IDs from JSON");
console.log(idsFromJSON);

let idsFromMarkers = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myMarkers);
console.log("IDs from myMarkers");
console.log(idsFromMarkers);

let jsonSet = new Set(idsFromJSON);
let markersSet = new Set(idsFromMarkers);

let difference = new Set(
    [...markersSet].filter(x => !jsonSet.has(x)));

difference.forEach(id => {
  //First you should delete marker from map
    //myMarkers[id].setMap(null);  //commented as we don't have real instances in this example
    //Now delete marker from hash
    delete myMarkers[id];
});

console.log("Markers after delete");
console.log(myMarkers);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I was able to work out a solution with your code. Thank you SO much!